# why php can not see /tmp files

Tags: files, systemd, php, tmp, sandbox

i have simple test.php page:

```
<pre><?php system("ls -la /tmp"); ?></pre>
```

which always shows just: `.` and `..` folders and nothing else in browser.

in the command line:

```
1) ls -la /tmp
2) sudo -u http ls -la /tmp
3) php test.php
4) sudo -u http php test.php
```

all this commands returns full list of directory files/subdirs.

What is the reason for this???

And problem is "/tmp" folder related because `ls -lah /usr` works OK.

i tested this on 4 comps (one of them was debian with php 5.0.6 and there php shows all files OK like i expected, other 3 comps has php7 and shows empty /tmp).

**update:**

even after adding http to sudoers file and running 'sudo ls /tmp', problem is the same on php versions >7.

but runing 'system("echo aaa > /tmp/aaa.txt; ls -la /tmp") shows `.` , `..` , and `aaa.txt` file owned by http:http. So is this some new php restriction and how it is posible to interfere on /tmp files only.

**update2:**

but aaa.txt is not inside /tmp, and by running `find /tmp -name aaa.txt`, i see that it is inside `/tmp/systemd-private-2cf1853410ad4ade980ec17e883771c3-httpd.service-lZ22gS/tmp/aaa.txt` .

so finaly it is related to something called "**systemd /tmp isolation**"... that i need to learn about.

Changing `true` to `false` inside: `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/httpd.service`:

```
[Service]
PrivateTmp=false
...
```

solves my problem, but i am wondering is it possible to avoid this without changing service file.

Comment: try to use `exec()` and `shell_exec()`

Comment: @Ravi, i did, all have same results (i use php 'system' for question because it simplifies output)

Comment: Have you tried with `sudo` ? it's work on my system !

Comment: @Ravi, tested now, same problem with sudo too (added to sudoers user http, sudo ls -la /tmp ... empty) ... maybe it is php version related. some bug or new restriction/config

Comment: Could you run `stat /tmp` in both cases and [edit] that into the question too?

Comment: On RaspberryPi with Noobs the file is a symlink
`/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service -> /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service`

Answer (score 5):

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and /usr/lib/systemd did not contain any services for http or apache2. However, I executed the following command:

```
sudo find / -mount -type f -exec grep -e "PrivateTmp" '{}' ';' -print
```

and found in **/lib/systemd/apache2.service** the **PrivateTmp=true**. Changing *true* to *false* and executing

```
systemctl daemon-restart
systemctl restart apache2
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: I don't think you should change the one in /lib, as that is managed by the package; instead, copy it to /etc and make your modifications there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I didn't realize there was a pecking order to how the systemd daemon processed files and that /lib shouldn't be touched. I'll make the change you suggested and retest.

Comment: Sure thing; check out https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html where it says "Example 2. Overriding vendor settings"

Answer (score 1):

> `<pre><?php system("ls -la /tmp"); ?></pre>`
>   ..
>   always shows just: . and .. folders and nothing else in browser.
>   ..
>   What is the reason for this???

Thats all the `system()` function is designed to do - it only returns the last line of output from the shell command.
So then why does a command exist that only gives you one useless line of output? possibly because [system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) allows you to capture  the exit code of the shell process (if you pass `$return_var` as a second argument) whereas `shell_exec` - which does give you all the shell output,  *doesn't give the exit code!*

So if you want all the output AND the exit code you can use `exec()`, but `exec` is a hassle because the full output is only available through the reference array `$output` which you then have to loop through to see your output.

Also, seeing as you are playing around in `/tmp`, you should be aware newer versions of PHP-FPM using `systemd` to manage the php-fpm daemon will pass a setting which blocks execution of php files from running out of tmp.
I have php 7.0.1 running on my laptop, but then I did an install of `7.1.1` and discovered they are now embedding this little directive

```
PrivateTmp=true
```

in the systemd service file. you need to set it to false if you want to run php scripts from `/tmp`
for more background on that particular issue
https://serverfault.com/questions/614781/php-script-cant-access-tmp-folder